# How to order time in y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I have a data frame (a tibble) like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
x = tibble(date=c("2022-04-25 07:04:07", "2022-04-25 07:09:07", "2022-04-25 07:14:07", "2022-04-26 07:04:07"),
              value=c("on", "off", "on", "off"))
x$day<- as.factor(day(x$date))
x$time <- paste0(str_pad(hour(x$date),2,pad="0"),":",str_pad(minute(x$date),2,pad="0"))
```

When I plot the data:

```
x %>% ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=day,y=time, fill=value))
```

[image]

the times in the y axis do not follow the bars. Each time data is supposed to be side by side with each bar segment.
I tried using `as.factor(time)` but that didn't solve.
I also tried to add a numeric scale:

```
x = tibble(date=c("2022-04-25 07:04:07", "2022-04-25 07:09:07", "2022-04-25 07:14:07", "2022-04-26 07:04:07"),
fake_y=c(1,1,1,1)
value=c("on", "off", "on", "off"))
x %>% ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=day,y=fake_y, fill=value))
```

but then the order of the on/off bars is lost.
[image]
How can I fix this?

Comment: You only have a single value for the 26th. How is that supposed to look?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what your desired plot should look like. Is this what want to do? `x %>% ggplot(aes(x=day, y=time, fill=value)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")`

Comment: @Aron: it is actually `x %>% ggplot(aes(x=day, y=time, fill=value)) + geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")`

Comment: @AllanCameron I've edited the post to show the (wrong) graphic. Hope it helps to understand.

Comment: @PauloS.Abreu your times are being read as factor levels, so they will not be proportional in the general case. Also, they shouldn't be stacked - it is the stacking that is ruining it.

Comment: @AllanCameron But I want the stacking in order to give the perception of a "timeline" (it was "on", then it went "off", then "on", etc).

Comment: @PauloS.Abreu but then how would day 26 look? Presumably it was 'on' until 07:04, which is designated as 'off'. If you use a bar labelled with 'off' it will give the impression of being 'off' until this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a time line, you would probably be best with `geom_segment` rather than `geom_col`. The reason is that since you might have multiple 'on' or 'off' values in a single day, it would be difficult to get these to stack correctly. You would also need to `diff` the on-off times to get them to stack. Furthermore, your labels would be wrong using columns if "off" represents the time of going from an on state to an off state.

When working with times in R, it is often best to keep them in time format for plotting. If you convert times to character strings before plotting, they will be interpreted as factor levels, and therefore will not be proportionately spaced correctly.

Since you want to have the day along one axis, you will need quite a bit of data manipulation to ensure that you record the state at the start of each day and the end of each day, but it can be achieved by doing:

```r
p <- x %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>%
  mutate(day = as.factor(day(date))) %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x,
          date = floor_date(as.POSIXct(first(.x$date)), 'day'), 
          value = ifelse(first(.x$value) == 'on', 'off', 'on'),
          .before = 1)) %>%
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x,
          date = ceiling_date(as.POSIXct(last(.x$date)), 'day') - 1,
          value = last(.x$value))) %>%
  mutate(ends = lead(date)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(ends)) %>%
  mutate(date = hms::as_hms(date), ends = hms::as_hms(ends)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = date)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = day, yend = ends, color = value),
               size = 20) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(25120, 26500)) +
  labs(y = 'time') +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 8)))

p
```

[image]

And of course, you can easily flip the co-ordinates if you wish, and apply theme elements to make the plot more appealing:

```r
p + coord_flip(ylim = c(25120, 26500)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('deepskyblue4', 'orange')) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16)
```

[image]